# How do get a list of available networks on Android AIR?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I tried googling but all I found was the NetworkInfo by Adobe and Freshplanets NetworkInfo ANE .   NetworkInfo for some reason isn't working and freshplanets network-info API can not do this. Is ther any other way to accomplish this task?

I downloaded this example from this link that uses networkInfo : [http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/networkinfo.html][1]

Here is the code the main class has in the above example:

/*

ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
Copyright 2011 Adobe Systems Incorporated
All Rights Reserved.

NOTICE:  Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file in accordance with the
terms of the Adobe license agreement accompanying it.  If you have received this file from a
source other than Adobe, then your use, modification, or distribution of it requires the prior
written permission of Adobe.

*/

```
package
{

import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.InterfaceAddress;
import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.NetworkInfo;
import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo.NetworkInterface;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

public class NetworkInfoUsageApp extends Sprite
{
    private var info:TextField;
    public function NetworkInfoUsageApp()
    {
        super();    

        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

        var ntf:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();

        info = makeTextField(50, 50);

        for each (var interfaceObj:NetworkInterface in ntf)
        {
            trace("Interface Name:" + interfaceObj.name + "\n" );
            trace("MTU:" + interfaceObj.mtu.toString + "\n" );
            trace("Display Name of the Interface:" + interfaceObj.displayName + "\n" );
            trace ("Active ?" + interfaceObj.active.toString() + "\n" );
            trace("Hardware Address:" + interfaceObj.hardwareAddress + "\n");



            info.appendText("Interface Name:" + interfaceObj.name + "\n" );
            info.appendText("MTU:" + interfaceObj.mtu.toString() + "\n" );
            info.appendText("Display Name of the Interface:" + interfaceObj.displayName + "\n" );
            info.appendText("Active ?" + interfaceObj.active.toString()+ "\n");
            info.appendText("Hardware Address:" + interfaceObj.hardwareAddress + "\n");

            for each(var address:InterfaceAddress in interfaceObj.addresses)
            {
                trace("Address" + address.address + "\n");
                trace("broadcast address" + address.broadcast + "\n");
                trace("ipversion" + address.ipVersion + "\n")
                trace("prefixlength" + address.prefixLength +"\n")

                info.appendText("Address" + address.address + "\n" );
                info.appendText("broadcast address" + address.broadcast + "\n" );
                info.appendText("ipversion" + address.ipVersion + "\n");
                info.appendText("prefixlength" + address.prefixLength +"\n" );

            }


        }


    }
    private function makeTextField(x:Number, y:Number):TextField
    {
        var tf:TextField = new TextField();

        tf.x = x;
        tf.y = y;
        tf.border=true;
        this.stage.addChild(tf);
        tf.height = 800;
        tf.width = 450;
        tf.type = "input";
        var tff:TextFormat=new TextFormat();
        tff.size=18;

        tff.color=0x0000ff;
        tf.defaultTextFormat=tff;
        tf.setTextFormat(tff);

        tf.text="hello";
        return tf;
    }
}
```

}

When I run the movie from Flash Pro, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Networkinfo::NetworkInfo/findInterfaces()[/Users/gangwar/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/NetworkInfoActionScriptLibrary/src/com/adobe/nativeExtensions/Networkinfo/NetworkInfo.as:70]
at NetworkInfoUsageApp()[C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\wifi test\NetworkInfoUsageApp\src\NetworkInfoUsageApp.as:39]
at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
at runtime::AppRunner/run()
at ADLAppEntry/run()
at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

And when I publish the apk and run it on my device. Nothing appears but white.

Comment: NetworkInfo does exactly that, why don't you explain what you are trying to do instead.

Comment: You're looking for a list of available WiFi networks? An ANE could likely do this, but what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Using networkInfo gives me this error.   Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: `NetworkInfo` doesn't do that, some code you wrote does that; show the code that throws that error.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: Like @TheDarkIn1978 said: check `NetworkInfo.isSupported` before calling `findInterfaces()`.

Answer (score 1):

**[NetworkInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInfo.html)** is not supported on all mobile devices.  Poll the **[isSupported](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInfo.html#isSupported)** flag to see if you have access.  If you do, simply call **[findInterfaces()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInfo.html#findInterfaces())** to retreive and array of [**NetworkInterface**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInterface.html) objects.

Answer (score 1):

I found out another awesome ANE for this that works perfectly. It's called "WifiTags". It works on both Windows and Android. Thanks to all those who answered.

[Tutorial for WifiTags](http://jsalatas.ictpro.gr/wifitags-an-adobe-air-native-extension-for-getting-available-wifi-networks-in-windows-and-android-environments/)